# counting checkboxes from an javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

This JavaScript function is in the webpage I am calling:

```
function getChecked(button, form) {

 var name;
 for (i = 0; i < document.forms['CheckForm'].list.length; i++) {
 name = "Check" + (i+0);
 if(document.forms['CheckForm'].list[i].checked == true) { 

 if(name == "Check0")
 form.Check0.value = "2437315";

 else if(name == "Check1")
 form.Check1.value = "2437104";

 else if(name == "Check2")
 form.Check2.value = "2434936";

 else if(name == "Check3")
 form.Check3.value = "2434574";

 else if(name == "Check4")
 form.Check4.value = "2433541";

 else if(name == "Check5")
 form.Check5.value = "2426021";

 }
```

Sometimes there are 6 checks, sometimes 7 sometimes 3, I need help in counting how many Check(Somenumber) there is and then build an post field with Check0=0&Check1=0&Check2=0 and so on.

I am not setting each check to different value, I need to count how many Checkboxes there are and then set them to 0, I am using PHP to cURL the page.

Comment: Any HTML you can add to get a better idea?

Comment: if I understood well your question which is not clear if you want to count your checked inputs and if you're jquery friendly, you can declare a variable var count = 0; $('input').each(function() {if $(this).is(':checked') count ++;}); /* let's suppose your inputs are of checkbox type*/ and then retrieve the value of count. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can do something like this:

```
var form = top.document.forms.CheckForm;
var numFormElements = form.length;
var counter = 0;
for( i = 0; i < numFormElements && !foundItem; i++ )
  {
    var obj = form[i];
    if( obj.type == 'checkbox' )
    {
      counter++;
    }
  }
 alert( counter ); // or whatever else
```

I should add... I don't think that there's any way that a server-side language can know the type of input. That information has to be grabbed from the user's web browser through a client-side means.

Comment: hello, i am not using javascript, I am curling the page with PHP and the javascript is in the called page, I need something in my php script that can count and build the curl post stsring

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply build the string as you go. There are other ways to do this (which I would suggest using jQuery with it and cycling through using "this"). Here is what I would do with your existing code.

```
//set a string
var values = '';

if(name == "Check0") {
    form.Check0.value = "2437315";
    values += 'Check0=' + form.Check0.value;
} else if(name == "Check1") {
    form.Check0.value = "2437315";
    values += 'Check1=' + form.Check1.value;
}
```

Comment: hello, i am not using javascript, I am curling the page with PHP and the javascript is in the called page, I need something in my php script that can count and build the curl post stsring